Test Cases Execution Order in XUnit
I've been writing Unit Tests for my application and have come across the TestCaseOrderer attribute when looking for a way to order my tests. I wish to execute my tests in a certain order, but also (if possible), order them so all tests run for the first inputs of a ClassData attribute, then for a second input and so on, sort of an Integration Test.
I wish to do this because my application consists of a sync workflow followed by an async workflow, consider it something as "Create" then "Process" workflows. I wished to execute the Create part then the Process part sequentially.
For example, if I had something like
public class CreateTestData : IEnumerable<object[]> {
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new object[]
        {
            ...
        };
        yield return new object[]
        {
            ...
        };
        yield return new object[]
        {
            ...
        };
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => GetEnumerator(); 
}

and
public class ProcessTestData : IEnumerable<object[]> {
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new object[]
        {
            ...
        };
        yield return new object[]
        {
            ...
        };
        yield return new object[]
        {
            ...
        };
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => GetEnumerator(); 
}

as input test data, and I wish to run the two tests mentioned above, with the first yield return of each ClassData being run on Create then Process, then the second yield return for the first then second tests, and so on... How could I achieve this? Is there a way or do I have to execute the two workflows (Create and Process) on a single test ensuring they would run one after the other for a set of inputs?

Sounds like there's something wrong about your software design, because there shouldn't be dependencies between tests. Unit tests by definition should be able to execute on their own without any prior conditions except for the test setup. Or I am misunderstanding your question.

I understand what you are saying, but I believe you didn't understand the purpose of what I'm trying to achieve. This is not meant to be a "Unit Test", but an "Integration Test" (example) for my whole workflow. As such, I need to test the workflow from beggining to end, and this can be achieved using XUnit framework. I already know a way to do this, I just am curious if there is an approach similar to what I asked.

Ah, okay. Shouldn't integration tests run in isolation as well?

It depends, you can run them with external dependencies, to test their integration.
Basicallty, depends on your tests objective.
